# Shell - Command ignoring extra parameters

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I've written a shell script that get's my IP address via `curl` from http://checkip.amazonaws.com

What i'm attempting to do is get a list of all my security groups and add that IP address to each security group via the AWS CLI.

The script I have so far is:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get IP Address
IP_ADDR="`curl http://checkip.amazonaws.com`"
IP_ADDR="$IP_ADDR/32"

cat /dev/null > /tmp/ec2.info

tmpFile="/tmp/ec2.info"

ec2Info=`ec2-describe-group --region eu-west-1 > $tmpFile`

sec_groups=`cat $tmpFile | grep GROUP | cut -f4`

echo "You are using IP Address:  $IP_ADDR"
echo ""

for security_group in $sec_groups
do

     echo ""
     echo $security_group
     echo ""

     ec2-authorize --region eu-west-1 $security_group –p 22 -s $IP_ADDR

done
```

The script works fine getting the IP address and a list of my security groups. However, I get an issue when the script gets to the `ec2-authorize` line.

I get an error message:

```
WARNING:  Ignoring extra parameter(s): [ ?p, 22 ]
Required option '-p, --port-range PORT-RANGE' missing (-h for usage)
```

As you can see from the script i've added the `-p` parameter specifying the port. It seems to be ignoring everything after the `$security_group` variable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a minus sign, you typed an en dash (Unicode U+2013). So just replace `–p` with `-p`.

I noticed in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21283832/4518341), you fixed this without realizing it. That's why it worked, not because you put the args into a var.

And this is why there was a question mark in the error message: `[ ?p, 22 ]`